# Referencing a GWT project from another GWT one - Problems

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

I am already using an open source GWT project (iServe) and I would like to integrate into it another open source GWT project (PetalsBPM), by which I mean being able to call it and reference its methods.

I have imported iServe in Eclipse (it has multiple modules) as separate Maven projects referencing its other and can run it successfully through Runas -> Web application in development mode.

If I do that and run the other project through the console as mvn gwt:run, I call initiate PetalsMBP through iServe. However, that means that the two programs have to run as is, without communication with each other.

I have also imported the second project into eclipse as a java project successfully (converting into a Maven one causes problems - various lifecycle configurations ones), but whenever I try to add to to iServe through Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects, although it does not cause any errors immediately, I cannot launch iServe anymore. It produces the following error:

*"Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:...iserve-sal-gwt-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long"*

Are my problems related to the fact that PetalsBPM is not a Maven project in Eclipse (I doubt it)?
Am I doing something wrong, i.e., this is not the way to reference a project from another one? should I add a reference to the first project's (iServe) gwt.xml file?
Is there a way to do what I want without having to wrap the second project as a jar and calling it from iServe? I would prefer not to, since producing a jar every time I make a slight change is not exactly efficient!

P.S: The second project is a regular GWT project with an entrypoint, not just a module. Should I remove this?

---

**UPDATE:** Trying to figure out the source of this error, I attempted to simplify the problem, so I performed the following moves:

1. I created two new simple GWT projects and tried to reference one
   from the other. Worked fine
2. I referenced the project I actually want
       to use (PetalsBPM) from the simple one I just created. Also works
       fine.
3. I referenced the new simple project from the original one I
           want to use (iServe). Also works fine.
4. Tried doing what I actually
       want to do, copying the settings from 2&3. Produces the same error
       "CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long" if
       I reference PetalsBPM (does not when I remove it from the referenced
       projects)

So, I tried switching workspaces. I created a new workspace in C:\, and moved the actual projects there. Still it did not work. :(

Any more ideas?

Comment: I figured out the problem, so I am posting the solution here for anyone that may face it in the future. The problem was not due to a single filename / pathname being too long, but that the request as a whole to the google eclipse plugin was too large. 

Specifically, the problem was caused by too many libraries/ jars being needed by the second project. Instead of just requiring less jars, I simply moved all the jars to C: and renamed them to files with two characters (a1, b9, etc) and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same type of error "Create Process, error=206, path too long etc." a hundred times.
Then, I found a solution/explanation in google-groups, it solved my problem. 
I post the content and link as it might help others.
This website (StackOverflow) really helped me a thousand times. 
Thanks to you all !

***solution/explanation*** :
(Response from Stephen Johnson)

> (...) if you're using eclipse plugin go to Project | Properties,  choose
>   Google \ App Engine \ ORM and only include directories that you  have
>   classes that you want enhanced. By default it does the entire  project
>   so that includes a lot of needless files. (...)

***Link*** : 
[original post @ google-groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/bN59FpWz7_M/discussion)

Answer (score 0):

Read the exception message again. Somewhere along the way Maven is generating a path that is too long for (some) Windows API to handle, try moving your workspace to a directory straight below `C:\`.

Comment: At first I thought so too. I tried shortening it first, but it didn't work. What DID work though, was just removing the second project from Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects of the first one.

So, I 'm guessing it has nothing to do with the actual length of the path.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion and moved the project to C:\ just in case. It didn't work.

Furthermore, I noticed that while Run as from Eclipse produces this error, if I try to do mvn gwt:run from the command line, it starts the development mode but not the project, complaining about an inherits line from the gwt (NOT the one referencing the other project)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried "skolima" reply and it worked for me.  In Eclipse I clicked File->Switch Workspace.

Three things to note:

1. After I created the workspace in "C:\workspace" I had to update my Project->Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs...
2. I'm using Windows 7.
3. I'm using "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers"

I hope this others.